(Solved) How can I align button images in XAML?
I am trying to create a vertical array of buttons using the following XAML:
<Window x:Class="SystemManager.Views.ServerSettings"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SystemManager.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Server Settings" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="220" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="20,20,5,5">
            <Button Margin="5" Click="PS_Click" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="0">
                    <Image Source="/Views/ps_small.png" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Production Server" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button Margin="5" Click="IS_Click" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="0">
                    <Image Source="/Views/is_small.png" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Imaging Server" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button Margin="5" Click="NP_Click" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="/Views/netpub_small.png" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10" />
                    <TextBlock Text="NetPub/WatchFolder" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button Margin="5" Click="MS_Click" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="/Views/RSMIcon.png" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Messaging Server" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button Margin="5" Click="BS_Click" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="/Views/bs_small.png" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Bridge Server" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>


See picture:

I tried using padding and margins to no avail.  I added the FlowDirection after reading another post, but it didn't do anything either.

Set HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" on the Buttons.

You can use ImageButton to reduce the code and performance. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/imagebutton?view=net-maui-8.0

Setting HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" on the buttons worked.  Thanks, Clemens.  BTW, I can't see how to mark this as the answer.

@DaveBurns you can create an answer to your question with your updated XAML, screenshot, and a note giving credit to Clemens. Then, mark that answer as Accepted,
